# Ошибка при выполнении нагрузочного тестирование back-end

Tags: jmeter

Провожу нагрузочное тестирование back-end и при выполнении теста через какое то время запросы начинают падать с ошибкой
Non HTTP response code: java.net.BindException/Non HTTP response message: Address already in use: connect
Как правильно настроить тест план чтобы эта ошибка ушла или из-за чего она может выходить?
Вот мой тест план и результаты тестов[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDOo3.png)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Это не проблема "тест плана", это проблема вашей операционной системы.

1. [Увеличьте количество портов](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/filenet-p8-platform/5.2.1?topic=listener-windows), доступных пользователю
2. [Уменьшите время](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/filenet-p8-platform/5.5.x?topic=system-recycling-tcp-connections-microsoft-windows-operating), которое потоки проводят в состоянии TIME_WAIT
3. Увеличьте [максимальное количество сетевых соединений](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/filenet-p8-platform/5.5.x?topic=itspmwos-increasing-maximum-number-tcp-connections-microsoft-windows-operating-system)

Со стороны JMeter я могу только посоветовать настроить [повторение неудачных запросов](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#httpclient4), для этого вам нужно поменять некоторые [JMeter Properties](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#httpclient4) типа `httpclient4.request_sent_retry_enabled` и `httpclient4.retrycount`

Comment: А от того что он такое большое кол-во Samples создает ничего страшного?

Comment: 100 пользователей за 5 минут создадут столько "Samples" сколько успеют, зависит от времени отклика тестируемого приложения. Если вы хотите "притормозить" JMeter - используйте соответствующие [таймеры](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-timer)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Так же я тут попробовал через обычный Thread group со 1000 пользователями и бесконечными loop, там он у меня в районе 5 минут работал нормально и без ошибок, пока я его не выключил сам. Может не в ОС дело выходит?